# How do I specify the layout of plots in ggcompetingrisks?

Tags: r, survival

Below is a sample code:

```
set.seed(2)
failure_time <- rexp(100)
status <- factor(sample(0:3, 100, replace=TRUE), 0:3,
                 c('no event', 'death', 'progression','other'))
disease <- factor(sample(1:6,  100,replace=TRUE), 1:6,
                  c('BRCA','LUNG','OV','CANCER','AIDS','HEART'))

fit <- cuminc(ftime = failure_time, fstatus = status,
               group = disease)

ggcompetingrisks(fit)
```

R automatically generations a plot that is organized in 3 columns, 2 rows. I would like it to be arranged as two columns, and three rows. Is there a way to do with ggcompetingrisks, or would I have to plot everything from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option that does this that I'm aware of. Meaning you should change the functions code:

1. Call function code with:

   `trace(survminer:::ggcompetingrisks.cuminc, edit = T)`
2. On line 23 add `ncol = 2`, to `facet_wrap(~group)` like:

   `pl <- ggplot(df, aes(time, est, color = event)) + facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 2)`
3. plot normally:

   `ggcompetingrisks(fit)`

[image]

Comment: I didn't know you could do that (change the functions code)! That worked beautifully. Thank you.